# How in Golang use struct in other package file?

Tags: go

I am new in **Golang** and need some help.

As you can see in the code below I am tring to create REST API in Golang. I use `mux` (Gorilla Mux) and `pq` (PostgreSQL driver) as third party libraries. Don't want to use ORM.

Inside `application.go` file I have `InitializeRoutes` function with a list of all aviable routes. `GetFactors` function process one of these routes. I am tring to define `GetFactors` function logic in other file called `factors.go`. Inside `factors.go` file I want to use `Application` struct which was defined in `application.go`. How to make it correctly? Right now as you can see they are in different packages. For thats why `factors.go` file don't see `Application` struct.

**Project structure**:

```
main.go
application.go
controllers
    factors.go
```

**main.go:**

```
package main

func main()  {
    application := Application{}
    application.Initialization()
    application.Run("localhost:8000")
}
```

**application.go**:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "rest-api/configurations"
)

type Application struct {
    Router *mux.Router
    Database *sql.DB
}

func (application *Application) Initialization() {
    var err error
    application.Database, err = configurations.DatabaseConnection()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    application.Router = mux.NewRouter()
    application.Router.StrictSlash(true)

    application.InitializeRoutes()
}

func (application *Application) Run(address string) {
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(address, application.Router))
}

func (application *Application) InitializeRoutes() {
    application.Router.HandleFunc("/api/factors", application.GetFactors).Methods("GET")
    // other code
}
```

**controllers/factors.go**:

```
package controllers

import (
    "net/http"
)

func (application *Application) GetFactors(rw http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    // code
}
```

Comment: In Go you cannot declare methods in one package on types that were defined in another package. To be able to declare `GetFactors` you would have to move `Application` into the `controllers` package.

Comment: Go also disallows cyclic imports, e.g. if package A imports package B, then package B cannot import package A, so just keep that in mind when you're refactor your design.

Comment: Hello! I am tring to adhere DRY (don't repeat yourself) concept. So use `Application` struct in both files are not good idea for my opinion. As variant in `factors.go` file I changed package name at top as `package main`. I don't know why `factors.go` file don't see `Application` struct although both files are in the same package. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @mkopriva I think the main issue here is that go cannot import package main, and `Application` can be placed in any package other than `main`, then it can be used by import that package.

Comment: @cgcgbcbc from different answers I just got confused. I tried to change package name in `factors.go` file. It didn't work for me. So can I import `main` package in `factors.go` file?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek `main` package **cannot** be imported by other package. You can move `Application` to package `controllers`, or create another package, for example, `package app`. Then you import package controllers or app where you will use `Application`

Comment: Ok, I created `application` folder. Inside that folder I created `application.go` file. Package name is `application`. How I can call `Application` struct in `factors.go` file? Can you show right way please?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek, reference it using `application.Application`, just like what you have written in your post: `http.ResponseWriter`, which reference a type `ResponseWriter` in package `http`

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek The best advice is: Start simple, do not complicate your solution by forcing the solution under some random concepts like DRY or SOLID or WHATNOT until you understand how to do this in Go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, finally I decided to redesign the project structure.

```
main.go
routes
    routes.go
controllers
    factors.go
models
    factors.go
```

**main.go**:

```
import (
    "your_project_name/routes"
)

func main()  {
    // code
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    routes.Use(router)
    // code
}
```

**routes/routes.go**:

```
package routes

import (
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "your_application_name/controllers"
)

func Use(router *mux.Router) {
    router.HandleFunc("/api/factors", controllers.GetFactors).Methods("GET")
}
```

**controllers/factors.go**:

```
package controllers

var GetFactors = func(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    // code
}
```